# After adding and removing jars to my endorsed directories, Eclipse gives me errors on all projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I was playing with JAXWS 2.2.7 on Java 1.6, so I needed to upgrade the API by adding jars to the jre/lib/endorsed directory as per [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/).

This worked fine, but after some consideration, I decided to roll back to the older version of the API by removing the libs from the endorsed directory. But this left me with the following error on all of my projects.

```
The container 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]' references non existing library '/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/endorsed/jaxws-api.jar'
```

Clearly eclipse added some kind of meta-data that references the jar file, but wasn't smart enough to remove the meta-data property when we removed the JAR file.

I've searched in vain for this meta-data in the project directory and in the eclipse install directory.  Can anyone help?

These are my platform details:

```
Eclipse Juno   Build id: 20120614-1722
Fedora 15
jdk1.6.0_21
```

Comment: I'm not sure but look at Preferences>Java>Installed JREs>{jre6?}>Edit>JRE Definition. System libraries are defined there and can be edited.

Comment: That where I expected to find it.  But it's not there.  Thanks.